Recommended way to handle and listen for UDP traffic on AWS server
We need to listen for traffic through UDP connection. There will be Garbage type & JSon objects received on an EC2 instance. I have configured a UDP port and enabled communication via EC2 public IP and defined port. A connection is established between the EC2 and 3rd party servers (Raspberry Pi).
In the EC2 instance, a PHP WebSocket script  reads incoming data and stores it in a MySQL database.
I am concerned with the security of this architecture.
Is AWS providing such services?
How can I make this UDP connection more reliable and secure?
I have little knowledge of networking. The  connection is established and working, but I believe it should be configured properly.
Thank you!

Currently this isn't a question that can be answered. WebSockets without HTTP/3 and QUIC is TCP based, so opening a UDP port is irrelevant. What kind of data traffic do you need to handle? If you explain more details, people might be able to give some options.

Your question is a bit broad and vague to answer. Suggest you make it more precise and specific. Simply opening a UDP port to the internet means anyone can connect to it.

@LexLi I have edited the question. can you help me out?

We had a requirement to listen to data traffic through UDP connection. That implies a lot of things.  Is there a format specified for the data?  Is there a protocol that is used to provide reliability?  Is there any encryption specified?  If there's none of that, and the sender is just sending unencrypted data via UDP packets with no way to ensure reliability while validating who the sender is, it's neither secure nor reliable.  Anyone could send data and you have a hard time knowing, and you wouldn't know if any data was dropped - because any network device can drop any UDP packet it wants.

Security is generally applied at the service level. For standard protocols such as HTTP AWS provides security tools such as WAF. But for your custom protocol you're on your own.

AWS providing such services dedicatedly? No. It shouldn't matter though. AWS only provides those types of features when there is enough demand. There's nothing to prevent you from providing your own security, independent of the service or even the transport.
